# Constant SSL handshake errors from random IP's on fresh server

Tags: security, ssl, web-server, log-files

I just set up a new server from, I've got as far as the following:

- Secured it (no root or password logins, UFW etc)
- Installed a LEMP stack.

After tailing the nginx error log, I'm seeing *constant* errors, which look like attempts to compromise the SSL from Iranian & Russian IP's. For example:

```
2019/09/23 17:42:38 [crit] 6611#6611: *5000095 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F0C6:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:packet length too long) while SSL handshaking, client: 5.234.166.113, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2019/09/23 17:42:40 [crit] 6611#6611: *5000225 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F0C6:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:packet length too long) while SSL handshaking, client: 31.2.143.221, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2019/09/23 17:42:48 [crit] 6611#6611: *5001090 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F0C6:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:packet length too long) while SSL handshaking, client: 89.36.99.104, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2019/09/23 17:42:49 [crit] 6611#6611: *5001232 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F0C6:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:packet length too long) while SSL handshaking, client: 86.57.113.197, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2019/09/23 17:42:50 [crit] 6611#6611: *5001276 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F0C6:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:packet length too long) while SSL handshaking, client: 5.121.174.179, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2019/09/23 17:43:00 [crit] 6611#6611: *5002221 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F0C6:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:packet length too long) while SSL handshaking, client: 5.74.187.51, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2019/09/23 17:43:00 [crit] 6611#6611: *5002250 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F0C6:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:packet length too long) while SSL handshaking, client: 178.236.102.93, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2019/09/23 17:43:01 [crit] 6611#6611: *5002327 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F0C6:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:packet length too long) while SSL handshaking, client: 5.106.78.245, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2019/09/23 17:43:05 [crit] 6611#6611: *5002733 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F0C6:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:packet length too long) while SSL handshaking, client: 178.236.102.93, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2019/09/23 17:43:12 [crit] 6611#6611: *5003431 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F0C6:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:packet length too long) while SSL handshaking, client: 5.212.171.209, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2019/09/23 17:43:19 [crit] 6611#6611: *5004092 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F0C6:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:packet length too long) while SSL handshaking, client: 5.115.250.119, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2019/09/23 17:43:29 [crit] 6611#6611: *5005018 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F0C6:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:packet length too long) while SSL handshaking, client: 158.58.64.8, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2019/09/23 17:43:34 [crit] 6611#6611: *5005514 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F0C6:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:packet length too long) while SSL handshaking, client: 31.59.166.195, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2019/09/23 17:43:37 [crit] 6611#6611: *5005762 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F0C6:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:packet length too long) while SSL handshaking, client: 31.2.170.98, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2019/09/23 17:43:37 [crit] 6611#6611: *5005792 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F0C6:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:packet length too long) while SSL handshaking, client: 31.59.166.195, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

Is this because my host co. have assigned me a dirty IP that was the target of previous attacks, or is it something more benign?

Either way, unless I can resolve it, the logs are going to fill up reasonably fast.

Answer (score 1):

This seems not to be a security issue. Please have a look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28010608/9361998

As a workaround (if you want to stop these request) you can ban the ip address with the following script

#### NOTE: Be sure to run as root

The theory is very simple:

1. Read the nginx and filter the ssl handshake error
2. Create a python script able to create an 'iptables ban' command based on a treshold (hardcoded)

If you have python installed you can run this simple script

```
import sys
import re

# Save the input data into a string
raw = sys.stdin.read().strip()

BAN_COUNT = 3
# Split the lines of the log
data = raw.split("\n")
to_ban = {}
# Iterate the lines
for item in data:
    # Extract IP
    ip = re.findall(r"[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}", item)
    # Due to the filter, we can have only 1 IP
    if len(ip) == 1:
        # print("Found IP to BAN -> {}".format(ip[0]))
        # If IP alredy found increase counter
        if ip[0] in to_ban:
            to_ban[ip[0]] += 1
        # First time that we encounter the IP, create new entry in dict
        else:
            to_ban[ip[0]] = 1
# Create iptables mask for ban
for keys in to_ban.keys():
    if to_ban[keys] >= BAN_COUNT:
        # BAN MASK
        # Use this for ban
        # ban_mask = 'iptables -A INPUT -s {} -j DROP'.format(keys)
        # Use this for test purpouse
        ban_mask = 'echo "iptables -A INPUT -s {} -j DROP"'.format(keys)
        print(ban_mask)
```

Now that we have a python script that take the input lines, extract the ip, count how many times they compare in text and print the iptables command for ban the ip, we can parse the `nginx` log.

Save the script as `ban.py`

```sh
cat /var/log/nginx | egrep "1408F0C6" | python ban.py | xargs command
```

In this method you are going to ban every ip that fall in handshake error.